# Class 'PHPExcel' not found in Excel5.php

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm getting the following error in PHPExcel:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in [...]/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel5.php on line 587
```

This is pretty odd, because I haven't encountered it searching on the net. PHPExcel works in its original location which uploads to an HTTPS server (where everything works fine), which is from where I copied it.

The line in PHPExcel where the error actually occurs:

```
$this->_phpExcel = new PHPExcel;
```

Any ideas or suggestions at all would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What version, and how are you including the PHPExcel classes in your script? And are you running PHPExcel with any other libraries or frameworks that might have their own autoloader code that could interfere with the PHPExcel autoloader?

Comment: The most recent version (1.7.6). Was being used at the same time as PHPMailer, but that was not present when it had failed to work in another piece of code, on the same server, elsewhere. It has since been fixed (explanation as answer). (Thanks for response.)

Comment: Still i have same error on PHPExcel 1.8 and PHP 7.0.8. any idea..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've since fixed this by reinstalling the whole package. Not at all sure what individual file or configuration would have caused the error, might have been to do with previous person to use that code. But anyway, fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
//before
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
```