# Class 'PHPExcel' not found in../HTML.php on line 153

Tags: php, html, class, phpexcel

I'm having a difficult time getting PHPExcel to work. In the class HTML.php, where the object is declared, `$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();` (on line 153), it can't seem to load PHPExcel. The entire error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'PHPExcel' not found in
>   /home/main/public_html/home/IEW/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php on line 153

The PHPExcel Library is located at /home/main/public_html/home/IEW/PHPExcel/

(My host is GoDaddy with cpanel is that makes any sort of difference).

Thanks!

Comment: did you included it like this? `include_once('PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');`

Comment: @jakob Wow that was it. I feel kinda dumb now not realizing that wasn't there. Thanks!

Comment: yea most of the time it is some dumb thing, it happens to us all :) I added answer so we can close this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PHPExcel to work properly you have to include `PHPExcel.php` like this:

`include_once('PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');`

Also, in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586247/class-phpexcel-not-found-in-excel5-php) reinstalling whole package can help.